# Outbound URL Rewriting - Only possible in IIS URL Rewrite module?

Tags: iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

Nobody using Apache mod_rewrite seems to understand what Outbound rule writing is, so I'm confused with this matter.

When developing a web application, you are naturally going to have long 'ugly' links because otherwise your IDE will not have a clue which files you are trying to link to. But when the webpages are being served to the user, you want them all to be presented in user-friendly URLs.

How are you supposed to include user-friendly URLs within your webpage before they are served to the user by the web server? If you manually have to change these types of links:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com?article=1&section=5">Article 1, Chapter 5</a>
```

into these type of links:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/article-1/section-5">Article 1, Chapter 5</a>
```

within your application code then you will mess up your entire application. Links will appear broken when you try validate the site and the site may look a mess.

So how are people including user friendly URLs in their applications without using Outbound rules?

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off working through your IIS URL Rewrite issues so you can make use of the outbound rewrite feature rather than trying to use mod_rewrite.

Comment: I jumped over to mod_rewrite only to realise that it doesn't support Outbound rule rewriting like IIS Rewrite Module does. In which case I can just use IIS Rewrite Module without Outbound rules. Hence I am now wondering how to do URL rewriting without Outbound rules....

I've tried working through my issues with IIS Rewrite module outbound rules but I've come to a dead end. ColdFusion simply doesn't like it and my pages are not loading correctly with Outbound rules turned on :(

Comment: Hop back over to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838484/coldfusion-with-iis-url-rewrite-page-never-finishes-loading) and check my comment about the HTTP errors.